# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Response' objects

Tags: python

(Ignoring that g.text and p.content return "You're not authorised to view this content" from plug.dj) I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plugling.py", line 20, in <module>
    r.send('{"a":"auth","p":"'+g+'","t":'+t+'}')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Response' objects
```

When running this code:

```
import time
from websocket import create_connection
import requests
import calendar

slug = 'sfoc'
r = create_connection("wss://godj.plug.dj/socket")
t = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())

token = 'https://plug.dj/_/auth/token'
join = 'https://plug.dj/_/rooms/join'
pl = {'slug': 'sfoc'}

g = requests.get(token)
print g.text

p = requests.post(join, data=pl)
print p.content

r.send('{"a":"auth","p":"'+g+'","t":'+t+'}')
result = r.recv()
print result
r.close()
```

It didn't like me using %s for the variables either. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance and let me know if I haven't explained something clearly.

Comment: As said in Error `g` is a 'Response' objects, So you can not concatenate it with a string, you can use `g.text` here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a `Response` object:

```
g = requests.get(token)
# ...
r.send('{"a":"auth","p":"'+g+'","t":'+t+'}')
```

`g` is the response object. You wanted to get the *text value*:

```
r.send('{"a": "auth", "p": "' + g.text + '", "t":' + t + '}')
```

You may want to look at the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) if you are trying to send JSON data there:

```
r.send(json.dumps({'a': 'auth', 'p': g.text, 't': t}))
```